# Python findall using xpath and return all elements inbetween

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

how can i parse the following xml and return all child elements for each node?

```
...
<cpp:ifndef pos:start="70:1" pos:end="70:22">#<cpp:directive pos:start="70:2" pos:end="70:7">ifndef</cpp:directive> <name pos:start="70:9" pos:end="70:22">INC_FREERTOS_H</name></cpp:ifndef>
<cpp:define pos:start="71:1" pos:end="71:22">#<cpp:directive pos:start="71:2" pos:end="71:7">define</cpp:directive> <cpp:macro pos:start="71:9" pos:end="71:22"><name pos:start="71:9" pos:end="71:22">INC_FREERTOS_H</name></cpp:macro></cpp:define>
...
```

I would like to return all elements beween the cpp:ifndef and cpp:def

I am currently able to parse the cpp:ifndef & define node, using the following code:

```
root.findall(".//cpp:ifndef", namespaces)
root.findall(".//cpp:define", namespaces)
```

But this only return attributes of the items (pos:start & pos:end) and not the other elements like cpp:directive, macro and name.

Comment: What do you get from `print(ET.tostring(root.findall(".//cpp:ifndef", namespaces)[0], encoding="unicode"))`?

Comment: <ns0:ifndef xmlns:ns0="http://www.srcML.org/srcML/cpp" xmlns:ns1="http://www.srcML.org/srcML/position" xmlns:ns2="http://www.srcML.org/srcML/src" ns1:start="70:1" ns1:end="70:22">#<ns0:directive ns1:start="70:2" ns1:end="70:7">ifndef</ns0:directive> <ns2:name ns1:start="70:9" ns1:end="70:22">INC_FREERTOS_H</ns2:name></ns0:ifndef>

Comment: So the other elements are there. Keep getting them starting at the found elements `root.findall(".//cpp:ifndef", namespaces)[0].find("directive",namespaces)`.